# Running VBA in a Microsoft Access Report before Printing

Tags: ms-access, report

I've created a report which is used to display a customer's address along with a logo.

The logo filepath is stored in the customer record and is loaded into a picture using some vba in the On Load event.

```
Me!Image01.Picture = logoPath
```

This works fine when previewing but when using DoCmd.openReport and sending it straight to print the code is not run.

My question is how do I get the code, which works fine if executed, to run before the report is sent to the printer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your code in the `Detail_Format` event, it should work.

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Me!Image01.Picture = logoPath
End Sub
```